# same class have three different nib file using splitviewcontroller?

Tags: ipad, ios7, xcode5, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have two classes one is viewcontroller that include viewcontroller.h ,viewcontroller.m, viewcontroller.xib. Second is detailviewcontroller that include detailviewcontroller.h, detailviewcontroller.m , detailviewcontroller1.xib , detailviewcontroller2.xib , detailviewcontroller3.xib.

I use splitviewcontroller left side is viewcontroller.xib with tableview and has 3 option.

when I click on first option it show detailviewcontroller1.xib // for registration page
when I click on second option it show detailviewcontroller2.xib// view all data in table from database

when I click on third option it show detailviewcontroller3.xib // display chart related to table data ...

problem is how can I manage this three nib file ?????

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
   {
      // 
   }
  else if (indexPath.row == 1)
  {

  }
  else if (indexPath.row == 2)
 {

 }

}
```

please answer me I didn't know because I am new in iOS, I started to learn iOS programming.
please answer me .......

Comment: According to your comments it seem to me these .xib has different logic. So you should have different view controller for each  xib to accomplish your goal.

Comment: so it is not possible to take 3 .xib of same class as per my logic .because first xib take data from user . second xib display that data .and third xib display chart related that data .

Comment: It certainly is possible, but the explanation is a bit complex for a stack overflow answer.  Look up subclassing, storyboards, outlets, and take the CS193p class in iTunesU.